# Configure DD-WRT / wireless router firmware online

Tags: wifi, router, firmware

Is there a way to configure firmware such as DD-WRT for a wireless router online or through a software program **prior** to loading it on the device?

For example, let's say that I want to setup a wireless router for someone else remotely without the need for that person to configure the new router. If I configure the firmware in advance, all they need to do is load it on the router without having to do any configuration.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: This seems like a question better asked of the dd-wrt developers directly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same version firmware (same device, same build), you can set up your router how you want it, then download the backup configuration file.  From there, you can load the file on a freshly configured router elsewhere.

I think that's the closest you're going to get without actually compiling the router binary from source code to your liking:  http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Compiling_DD-WRT_Sources.